# Dart: How to create a future from multiple completers

Tags: flutter, dart, socket.io

I want to create a future from multiple completers in dart/flutter.

```
Future getAndWriteToDB(conversations){
    List<Completer> _completerList = List();

    for (var i = 0; i < conversations.length; i++) {
      final conversation = conversations[i];
      _completerList.add(Completer());
      SocketService()
          .listenForEvent('mylistenerkey')
          .then((data) {
         _messagesDao.insertMessages(messages).then((result) {
            if (result == false) {
              print("writing to db for message failed");
            } else {
              _completerList[i].complete(true);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }


    return {{ wait for these completers complete event }}
}
```

Here my `SocketService().listenForEvent` gets called whenever that event is available. I want to write all of my conversations to database then once all those are completed get to know that state.
So I need to wait for or create a future based on these list of completers. How can I achieve this?

Comment: tried `Future.wait`? also, if you have `.listenForEvent('mylistenerkey')` which is a `Future` you dont need your `Completer`s at all - simply use the `listenForEvent` return `Future`s in `Future.wait` call

Comment: `.listenForEvent()` is not a future, but I tried to make that into a future. But then how can I wait for all these listenForEvents() to complete if I didn't use Completer. The function linear execution will got exited right?

Comment: `listenForEvent()` returns a `Future` since you call `then()` on it - so inside your loop add that `Future` to some `List` and use it in `Future.wait()`

Comment: Okay. Got your point. But should the `listenForEvent() `future completed when it calls `then()` or when the nested `_messageDao().then()` also completed? Because I need to wait for the DB insert also

Comment: If I added the future of _messengerDao().then() then there is chance that the return statement gets called before assigning any futures to the list?

Comment: so shain your `Future`s like here: https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling#errors-in-the-middle-of-a-long-chain - notice that `then()` should return another `Future`

Comment: `one()
    .then((_) => two())
    .then((_) => three()
    .then((_) => four())`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Future.wait](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-async/Future/wait.html):

```
return Future.wait(_completerList.map((e) => e.future));
```

Comment: How can I process this returned map. I tried to convert it into list by `return Future.wait(_completerList.map((e) => e.future)).toList();` and on the calling function I tried to process the result by `List<bool> result = await getAndWriteToDB()`. But the returned type is `List<Future<dynamic>>` not `List<bool>` even I added  `_completerList[i].complete(true)` for completing the future.

Comment: I think I found the solution for the comment. I processed them with Future.wait(). Sorry, my bad. :)

Comment: Okay, I have one more question here. One of the function where I converted an event-callback pattern to Future using Completer is throwing Future already completed exception for events after the first successful event to Future conversion. Is there any way can I avoid this but still convert the callback pattern to a Future one??